# Why do iOS packages have different sizes on different iPhone devices?

Tags: ios, swift, package, size

I checked the build in the app store connect and found that different iPhone devices have different sizes. As shown in the figure below, the package size is 12.3MB on iPhone XS and other models, but on iPhone 11 and other models. It is 4.76MB. At first I thought it was a problem with the CPU specifications, but I found that the size of the package on the iPod touch 7 with A10 is 4.81MB, and I didn't find out why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

App Store optimize package for each target device. It's called App Thinning and you can check WWDC video about it here:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/404/

Long story short, package for specific target phone has only files and images relevant to that target.